# make div scroll left when window is scrolled left

Tags: jquery, css

I've tried something like below and it prints out "scroll" but the element #etable_body is not scrolled.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $("#Table_body").scrollLeft(window.scrollLeft);       
        console.log("scroll");
    });
```

Note, I only want Table_body to scroll left if I scroll left in window. Also if possible: don't move the "window" either when scrolling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Table_body`, `table_body` or `etable_body` ??

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tisaw/1/edit)**

Using https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/

```
var $tb = $('#Table_body');

$(window).on('mousewheel', function(e){
  var ns = $tb.scrollLeft() - (e.deltaFactor*e.deltaY)
  $tb.scrollLeft( ns ); 
});
```